# How to create / destroy tab dynamically in sencha touch 2

Tags: performance, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I have a list of tabs, what I want is whenever i switch a tab, the items are added to the tab and it is redrawn, and the old tab is destroyed. I'm doing this for performance reasons.

This is how i tried to do it, but its not working

```
view=    Ext.Viewport.add({                
                xtype : 'tabpanel',  
                deferredRender:false,
                tabBarPosition : 'bottom',
                items : tabs,
                listeners : 
                {
                    activeitemchange : function(container, newValue, oldValue,opts)
                    {
                        // --> destroy old tab
                        oldValue.setItems([]);
                        index = container.items.findIndex('id',newValue.id);
                        // --> redraw new tab                            
                        newValue.add(tabItems[index-1]);
                    }
                }
});
```

The tabs are loaded only the first time. The second time i enter a tab i get
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

What is the proper way to do this ?
And is this really more performant than creating the tabs with their items in them.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? Please be more specific

Comment: hi added the error in the question, I'm getting Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 when entering the second time my tab

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. It would mean the actual tabs will *also* be removed from your tabpanel. Is that what you want?

Surely you just want to remove the tabpanel *items* - right? If so, I suggest you do not use `tabpanel`, instead you should use a normal container with a card layout and then a `tabbar` component. That way, the tabbar can have several tabs, and the container (fake tabpanel) can *pretend* to have several items, but only have 1/2.

Comment: I though by setting items / removing items I'm actually removing only what's inside the tab. I'll try your way. thanks

Comment: this is a great answer! :) btw, please have a look at this question, I've encountered the same problems many times during optimization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208627/button-tap-not-reacting-when-view-gets-added-a-2nd-time