# Custom Event Listeners not added to Controller after Container got destroyed once

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

hopefully someone can shade some insight into this problem ... been banging my head against the wall for a while.

**Problem:**
I have a custom event called "showCommentPanel" attached to a View called "StoryDetailPanel". A delegate listener on "StoryDetailPanel" listen for a tap and then fire "showCommentPanel" inside the function. The event is caught in a Controller and do something. "StoryDetailPanel" is a dynamically created view that got pushed and removed from the navigation view. 
My problem is that this whole setup works when StoryDetailPanel was show the first time. Tap on DOM element was caught, event was fired and controller get event. However, after the "Back" button was pressed, and a new StoryDetailPanel was created, the Tap on DOM element was caught, but "showCommentPanel" was not caught in the controller anymore.

**Code:**

**StoryDetailPanel View**

```
Ext.define('Test.view.StoryDetailPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.storydetailpanel',

    config: {
        cls: 'storydetailpanel',
        id: 'storydetailpanel',
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                id: 'infodetailcontainer',
                itemId: 'mycontainer3',
                margin: '2% 5% 0px 5%',
                tpl: [
                    '<div class=\'detailinfo\'>',
                    '    <div class=\'container\'>',
                    '        <div class=\'actions\'>',
                    '            <div class=\'comments\'>',
                    '                <div class=\'text\'>COMMENT</div>',
                    '            </div>',
                    '        </div>',
                    '    </div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '',
                    ''
                ],
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'
                }
            }
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onCommentTap',
                element: 'element',
                event: 'tap',
                delegate: 'div.actions .comments'
            },
            {
                fn: 'onStorydetailpanelShowCommentPanel',
                event: 'showCommentPanel'
            }
        ]
    },

    onCommentTap: function(target) {
        alert('comment tapped: '+this.id);
        //TODO: remove hard coding later
        var postId = 7;
        this.fireEvent("showCommentPanel", postId);
    },

    onStorydetailpanelShowCommentPanel: function(postId, eventOptions) {
        alert("show comment panel caught in story detail");
    }

});
```

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('Test.controller.Post', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            storydetailpanel: 'storydetailpanel',
        },

        control: {
            "#storydetailpanel": {
                showCommentPanel: 'onStorydetailpanelShowCommentPanel',
            }
        }
    },

    onStorydetailpanelShowCommentPanel: function(postId, eventOptions) {
        alert('show event caught in controller');
    },

});
```

And the "StoryDetailPanel" was added to the navigation view like this

```
var details = Ext.create('Test.view.StoryDetailPanel', {
    title: 'Details'
});

this.getMainNav().push(details);
```

So here are the scenarios:

1. "Comment Tapped" is always alerted all time when the comment div is
   tapped
2. "show comment panel caught in story detail" is always alerted after "comment tapped"
3. "show event caught in controller" is only shown the **First Time** that storydetailpanel is shown. After hitting "back" and doing whatever that trigger a new storydetailpanel being pushed in. Tapping on the comment div would only trigger #1 and #2.

**EDITED** 
A little more info,
As long as I **DID NOT** press the back button (i.e. keep staying in the same StoryDetailPanel view the first time it is loaded), everything works and the event would be caught in the controller. So I suspect destroying the first instance of StoryDetailPanel has something to do with killing the listener?

I've scouted a lot on google and stackoverflow and couldn't find a solution ... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Instead of banging my head against the wall and doing the try and error I decided to dig into the sencha touch code, I think I by and large know what's going on now .....
Anyway, so first it would be useful to understand that listeners are being held inside a singleton called Dispatcher. And that listeners live and die with the caller object. So once the object got destroyed, the listener instances got removed from the Dispatcher. When an object got instantiated, event listeners for that container would be added back in. What happened is the "destroy()" call apparently broke whatever mechanism that governs what event listeners to be added while a new instance of the container is created (probably some residual tracker that didn't got cleared and that it skipped adding the listener without realizing that it has been removed).

This behavior is verified by me going through the listener stack in the dispatcher before and after the destroy() call as well as right after when the container is instantiated.

Anyhow, knowing this, the workaround becomes quite obvious, I think it is clean and non-intrusive enough that I am willing to live with it ... for now.

Basically when you are creating and destroying containers dynamically, just make sure you go the extra step of adding the listeners for your custom events after the firing container is created. So in my example

```
functionThatCreatesDetailPanelInController: function() {
var detailpanel = <Code that creats my detailpanel>
//add listener for custom event
detailpanel.on('showCommentPanel', this.onDetailpanelShowCommentPanel, this);

< add detailpanel into view ... >

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is what I'm doing all the time: binding events on views initialization

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the question. I have encountered this issue a lot of times when working with Sencha Touch from very early days.

There might be a chance to solve your problem in this post: [button tap not reacting when view gets added a 2nd time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208627/button-tap-not-reacting-when-view-gets-added-a-2nd-time)

But for me, it does not. That's the reason why I have moved from using Controllers for a quite long time because I don't believe it's a good practice to be used in large applications, in which we have to add and remove views very frequently.

I believe this is a bug.

Comment: I just did a quick scan on the post you linked to. Thanks for responding Thiem. I also edited my original question stating that as long as the view did not get destroyed, everything would work as expected. Conincidentally, the thread you linked mentioned about setting autodestroy to false .... so that says there's something really related to the destruction of the object. I just want to know if I should give up this [View -> fireevent-> Controller do busy work] paradigm that I am going after.